# Value and usage of Git-Flow's tag-prefix feature?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've been using [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) for a while but I still don't understand the Tag Prefix feature. I assume it's just a string that prefixes every `release/` tag. Does anyone have any usage examples or benefits of doing this? I've yet to see any explanation of it in any of the Git Flow blog posts.

Answer (score 9):

We use it to help with identifying the build that is in each of our environments.  Our release tag prefix is "stage-".

We name our releases with a date stamp - "041912"  When we do a "git flow release start 041912" a branch will be created called stage-041912 and we bump the version number to that tag name (trying to automate this - see my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228073/looking-for-a-way-automate-the-bump-version-with-git-flow) that I posted) in the footer.  Our QA team looks here to ID the version that they are using when they are writing tickets in our issue tracker.

This has worked very well for us in our release workflow.

HTH

Comment: Please link to the latest question you posted... :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228073/looking-for-a-way-automate-the-bump-version-with-git-flow